# Explanation on how this function process image using numpy and cv2

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, openai-gym

## The question

I have the following function:

```
    def process(frame):
        if frame.size == 240 * 256 * 3:
            img = np.reshape(frame, [240, 256, 3]).astype(np.float32)
        else:
            assert False, "Unknown resolution."
        img = img[:, :, 0] * 0.299 + img[:, :, 1] * 0.587 + img[:, :, 2] * 0.114
        resized_screen = cv2.resize(img, (84, 110), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        x_t = resized_screen[18:102, :]
        x_t = np.reshape(x_t, [84, 84, 1])
        return x_t.astype(np.uint8)
```

I know the high-level explanation of what the function does: resizing the image from `240x256` to `84x84` and converting it from RGB to grayscale. However, I would like to understand line-by-line what is going on.

## What I managed to deduce

Please correct me if any of my deductions/assumptions are wrong.

##### 1. `if frame.size == 240 * 256 * 3:`

It will check whether the image (in `numpy.ndarray` format) is 240 in height, 256 in width, and has 3 color channels (representing the RGB).

##### 2. `img = np.reshape(frame, [240, 256, 3]).astype(np.float32)`

It converts all the values in `numpy.ndarray` to `np.float32`.

##### 3. `img = img[:, :, 0] * 0.299 + img[:, :, 1] * 0.587 + img[:, :, 2] * 0.114`

It converts the image from RGB to grayscale by modifying the 3 RGB channels using this magical formula.

## Origin of the code (Context)

The code can be located [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/blob/9660bacc8f0e262aad9a6f902a0de29d249a60d0/Chapter06/lib/wrappers.py#L57). This code is part of a *Deep Reinforcement Learning* project, specifically for playing Atari games using the OpenAi `gym` environment.

The function is used to modify the screen data (trim out unnecessary data like colors and make it smaller) of the gym's NES emulator for the neural network to train faster.

Comment: also under assumption 2, `frame` is reshaped to the given dimension and also converted to `float` data type

Comment: yes, I meant 256 widths. That was a mistype.

Comment: assumption 3 is correct considering `img[:, :, 0]` is Red and `img[:, :, 2]` is Blue channel respectively

Comment: 1 only checks the number of elements, for instance, if `frame` is an 1D array of length `184320`, it will also pass. Considering this, 2 is not only converting the dtype, but also the shape.